# Response does not implement http.Hijacker

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm using Go and trying to implement WebSocket in my project. while implementing this. I get "WebSocket: response does not implement HTTP.Hijacker" error. I'm new to this technology. Can anyone help me resolve this?

```
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
} 

func HandleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("err", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("hello client")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The application is using "middleware" that wraps the net/http server's [ResponseWriter](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter) implementation. The middleware wrapper does not implement the [Hijacker](https://godoc.org/net/http#Hijacker) interface.

There are two fixes for the problem:

- Remove the offending middleware.
- Implement the Hijacker interface on the middleware wrapper by delegating through to the underlying response.  The method implementation will look something like this:

  ```
  func (w *wrapper) Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
      h, ok := w.underlyingResponseWriter.(http.Hijacker)
      if !ok {
          return nil, nil, errors.New("hijack not supported")
      }
      return h.Hijack()
  }
  ```

If you don't know what the response writer wrapper is, add a statement to print the type from the handler:

```
func HandleConnections(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("w's type is %T\n", w)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To cite the docs on `http.Hijacker`:

`~$  go doc http.Hijacker`

> ```golang
> package http // import "net/http"
>
> type Hijacker interface {
>   // Hijack lets the caller take over the connection.
>   // After a call to Hijack the HTTP server library
>   // will not do anything else with the connection.
>   //
>   // It becomes the caller's responsibility to manage
>   // and close the connection.
>   //
>   // The returned net.Conn may have read or write deadlines
>   // already set, depending on the configuration of the
>   // Server. It is the caller's responsibility to set
>   // or clear those deadlines as needed.
>   //
>   // The returned bufio.Reader may contain unprocessed buffered
>   // data from the client.
>   //
>   // After a call to Hijack, the original Request.Body must not
>   // be used. The original Request's Context remains valid and
>   // is not canceled until the Request's ServeHTTP method
>   // returns.
>   Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error)
> }
> ```
>
> The `Hijacker` interface is implemented by `ResponseWriters` that allow an
> HTTP handler to take over the connection.
>
> The default `ResponseWriter` for HTTP/1.x connections supports `Hijacker`,
> but HTTP/2 connections intentionally do not.
> `ResponseWriter` wrappers may also not support `Hijacker`.
> Handlers should always test for this ability at runtime.

So, I see several possibilities for your problem to happen:

- You're trying to turn an HTTP/2 connection to a Websocket.
- You're using some "middleware" which wraps whatever object the stock `net/http` package passes to your handler as `net/http.ResponseWriter` with something which does not bother to implement the proper `Hijack` method to support the `net/http.Hijacker` interface.

Comment: The HTTP/2 scenario is very unlikely because the Gorilla package checks for the WebSocket handshake headers before hijacking the connection. The only way hijack can fail this way is for a client to purposefully send the handshake over HTTP/2 instead of HTTP/1.1 as required by the protocol.