# How to implement http.Hijacker in middleware

Tags: go, gorilla

I tried to add websocket within my restful web server, but (maybe) because of the middleware block the ws response Hijacker, it cannot build the connection succeed.

```
// main.go
api := http.Server{
    ...
    Handler:      handlers.API(middleware...), // pass the needed middleware.
}

// handler.go
func API(middleware...) http.Handler {
    app := web.NewApp(middleware...)
    app.Handle(http.MethodGet, "/ws", wsHandler)
}
func wsHandler(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    }

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "")
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            ...
            return web.NewRequestError(err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }

        ...
    }

}

// web.go
type Handler func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error
type Middleware func(Handler) Handler
func (a *App) Handle(method, path string, handler Handler, mw ...Middleware) {
    handler = wrapMiddleware(mw, handler)
    ...
}
func wrapMiddleware(mw []Middleware, handler Handler) Handler {
    for i := len(mw) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        h := mw[i]
        if h != nil {
            handler = h(handler)
        }
    }

    return handler
}
```

Comment: If the middleware doesn't support `Hijacker`, you should not add support for it either. Once your handler returns, the middleware may attempt to do things that will fail if you allow hijacking the connection. The best and cleanest would be to not use the middleware for your handler in which you utilize hijacking.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980183/response-does-not-implement-http-hijacker/63096684#63096684.

Answer (score 1):

I found this example from http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/q7bs/access-log-middleware-in-golang really helpful:

```
// Overrides http.Hijacker type.
func (w *writer) Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
    hj, ok := w.ResponseWriter.(http.Hijacker)
    if !ok {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("the hijacker interface is not supported")
    }
 
    return hj.Hijack()
}

// Overrides http.Flusher type.
func (w *writer) Flush() {
    if fl, ok := w.ResponseWriter.(http.Flusher); ok {
        if w.resStatus == 0 {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        }
 
        fl.Flush()
    }
}
```

After minimal adjustments to my data structures I was able to still use my websocket and the logging middleware I copied together from SO.